# JavaScript Switch Case Not Considering All Cases

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a rock paper scissors game. I have a function that checks who won. I'm using a switch case that evaluates "switch (`${userChoice}-${cpuSelection}`)" and then certain cases lead to wins, losses, or ties. However, when I select "rock", I can't tie. When I select "paper", I can't win. And when I select "scissors", I can't lose. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
// Randomly generates CPU choice
function getCpuChoice() {
    const cpuChoice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
    cpuMessage.textContent = `${cpuName.textContent} chose ${cpuChoice[random]}`;
    return cpuChoice[random];
}

// Adds score to user and displays win message
function winRound() {
    userScore.textContent++;
    resultMessage.textContent = "You Win!"
}

// Adds score to CPU and dislays loss message
function loseRound() {
    cpuScore.textContent++;
    resultMessage.textContent = "You Lose!"
}

// Displays tie message
function tieRound() {
    resultMessage.textContent = "Tie!"
}

// Determines winner
function result(userChoice) {
    const cpuSelection = getCpuChoice();
    switch (`${userChoice}-${cpuSelection}`) {
        case "rock-scissors":
        case "paper-rock":
        case "scissors-paper":
            winRound();
            break;
        case "rock-paper":
        case "paper-scissors":
        case "scissors-rock":
            loseRound();
            break;
        case "rock-rock":
        case "paper-paper":
        case "scissors-scissors":
            tieRound();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of having all the matching choices as individual case statements I'd probably check/return tieRound() if userChoice == cpuSelection before your switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `switch` is fine, but the problem is:

```
 const cpuChoice = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
 const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
```

This will give you random numbers between 1 and 3, when you really need between 0 and 2 for array indices.

If you change this to `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)`, you should be good.

Comment: Nice catch! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I see an issue totally unrelated to your switch - your random selection is wrong!

```js
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3 + 1);
```

This will give you randomly either `1`, `2` or `3`, since `0 <= Math.random() < 1`, multiplied by 3 that gives `0 <= x < 3` and adding 1 gives `1 <= x < 4`.

But, this creates a problem! This means that with the array `["rock", "paper", "scissors"]`, you will randomly get one of the following values...

```js
random[1] // "paper"
random[2] // "scissors"
random[3] // undefined
```

As you can see, you are off by one here with the index. The issue is the `+ 1`. You want `0`, `1` or `2`, not `1`, `2` or `3`:

```js
random[0] // "rock"
random[1] // "paper"
random[2] // "scissors"
```

Removing the `+ 1` should solve your problem.

Comment: Nice catch! Thanks for the help!